# Admin Password Changed, Need to Revert

Tags: active-directory, password

Im kinda new to network administration.
  I was asked to change the password on our SQL Server.  The only account that is used to log in is the Administrator account.

I did a dumb thing and reset it through Ctrl+Alt+Delete > "Change Password". The admin password got reset for the whole domain.  I tried to reset it (through the same method) but im gettin an error stating that the password cannot be one that was recently used.

**Question:**  Is the best solution to reset the password through Active Directory?  Or does anyone have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like there is a password policy in place that is stopping you from doing that (reusing the same last x number of passwords). Unless there are services running throughout the domain using the Domain Administrator account (which is a huge no no), document the new password and leave it be.

If you absolutely need to revert it back, you will need to login as another domain admin, and reset the password manually through Active Directory Users and Computers.

Comment: Thanks Dan,  This answers my question.  I'll just inform everyone of the change.

Comment: Alternately, the OP can (could have) changed the password to a bunch of different values, and then back the original.  Windows domain password complexity contains a history value, and a setting to prevent changing a password to a value used the last x times.  So change the password x times, then you can change it back to the desired value.  Three cheers for the inconvenience == security approach to password policies.